# if else code block execution

Tags: javascript

I have a simple if-else code block as following. It looks simple but I cannot explain its behavior: if the "else" block is NOT included, then the code line (1*) is always hit !  But if I add an "else" block, then the code line (2*) is hit.

```
var startTime = '11:35 PM';
var endTime = '4:40 PM';

if (startTime.indexOf('12:') >= 0 && endTime.indexOf('12:') < 0) {
      return true; // code line (1*)
}
else
{
      return false; // code line (2*)
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: sounds like you have a `return true` after the if/else

Comment: You must be mistaken, if you remove the else block the function should just return undefined (assuming that's from a function, otherwise using return will result in an error).

Comment: How are you determining which line is hit? You sure it's not a truthy/falsey issue?

Comment: Is this code executing inside a function? A return statement outside of a function is invalid. Just a wild guess. When I run that code inside a function, it works fine.

Comment: What you're telling us is not correct: http://jsfiddle.net/ww4uN/ . This code does not do what you're describing. You should really try to make sure that your code actually exhibits the problem before asking about it or you're basically just making everyone try to guess what your *real* code is.

Comment: You have not included enough context beyond the code you currently show for anyone to know what is really causing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following function:

```
function randomName () {

  var startTime = '11:35 PM';
  var endTime = '4:40 PM';

  if (startTime.indexOf('12:') >= 0 && endTime.indexOf('12:') < 0) {
      return true; // code line (1*)
  }
  else {
      return false; // code line (2*)
  }

  return true;
}
```

This would exhibit the behavior you describe.  Without the else part it would always return true.  Is this what you have?  If not please show the rest of the function.  Also helpful would be to see your test case.